# команда фильтр grep

Tags: linux, centos8

задача:
в файле содержащем текст и ip адреса вывести только уникальные адреса (команды `grep`, `uniq`)

Текст:

```
        test 127.0.0.1 test test
        # this is 192.196.31.12 ip addr
        8.8.8.8
        dns ad127.0.0.1dr
```

Результат:

```
        127.0.0.1
        192.196.31.12
        8.8.8.8
```

Помогите решить, по строкам, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oP '(?<=[^0-9]|^)(?:1?[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9])\.(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:1?[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9])(?=[^0-9]|$)' /file ...
```

Далее нужно выполнить сортировку по значениям, иначе unuq не сработает и объединяет только подряд идущие идентичные записи, сделать это можно командой `sort`

```
... | sort | uniq
```

Но у sort есть параметр выбрать сразу уникальные записи и команда в целом будет выглядеть так:

```
grep -oP '(?<=[^0-9]|^)(?:1?[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9])\.(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:1?[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9])(?=[^0-9]|$)' /file | sort -u
```

---

Регулярное выражение `(?<=[^0-9]|^)(?:1?[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9])\.(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:1?[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9])(?=[^0-9]|$)` сделал что бы выбирать валидный ip адрес, проще конечно проверять каждый октет на < 256
Пример работы: https://regex101.com/r/ob48gv/3
начала диапазона 1.0.0.1 и до 255.255.255.255

Comment: _grep -w ..._ иногда упрощает жизнь.

Comment: **-w, --word-regexp      ШАБЛОН должен подходить ко всем словам**, согласен, параметр действительно хорош, спасибо, потестирую на досуге.

Answer (score 0):

cat text.txt | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | sort --unique

Comment: `0x0y0z0` тоже совпадает.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po '[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+' file | sort | uniq
```

Comment: 1. `-r` зачем? 2. `0x0y0z0` тоже совпадёт

Comment: -r - чтобы регэксп заработал. наверное тут надо точку еще заэкранировать, чтобы именно точка была, а не любой символ

Comment: а что у вас в `$ man grep` написано про опцию `-r`?

Comment: recursive :D ну да, -r лишний явно тут.